# Qt Linux/Windows cross compilation. Compile qmake for Windows binaries on Linux for Qt Creator

Tags: linux, windows, qt, cross-compiling, qt6

I think I have a big misunderstanding about how to use Qt Creator and qmake to compile Windows binaries on a Linux host. I set up a Debian 11 VM on my server to compile some tools originally written for Linux. Now I want to port these programs to Windows and setting up a Windows (virtual) machine is not an option. Another important requirement is the static linking option, which requires a custom build of Qt6.

I can easily build Qt 6.2.4 (and qmake) for Linux and use it in Qt Creator 8 to compile my tools for Linux machines. Now I need a cross compiler (mingw-w64) for windows binaries and therefore a new version of qmake made specifically for this purpose (at least I think so). But when I use the cross compiler for qmake I get a windows binary `/usr/local/qt6-win32/bin/qmake.exe` which of course cannot be used in the Linux version of Qt Creator. Here's the problem - or misunderstanding - of how to cross-compile with Qt.

Here's a full list of what I've done so far:

```
# install requirements:

$ apt build-dep qtbase5-dev
$ apt install libgl1-mesa-dev git cmake/bullseye-backports ninja-build \
  llvm '^libxcb.*-dev' libxrender-dev libxi-dev gdb gcc-mingw-w64 \
  g++-mingw-w64 gdb-mingw-w64
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

# build and install qt6 (linux):

$ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git ~/.qt_src
$ cd .qt_src/
$ git checkout 6.2
$ perl init-repository
$ ./configure -prefix /usr/local/qt6 -static -opensource -confirm-license \
  -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine
$ cmake --build . --parallel
$ sudo cmake --install .

# clean build:

$ cmake --build . --target clean && \
  git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx" && \
  git clean -dfx

# build and install qt6 (windows cross-compiler):

$ wget https://gist.github.com/peterspackman/8cf73f7f12ba270aa8192d6911972fe8/raw/56ec269dc412a1055d00c4a810e6794283bc7dd4/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake
$ ./configure -platform linux-g++ -xplatform win32-g++ \
  -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32- \
  -prefix /usr/local/qt6-win32 -qt-host-path /usr/local/qt6 \
  -static -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples \
  -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine \
  -- -DQT_BUILD_TOOLS_WHEN_CROSSCOMPILING=ON \
  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake
$ cmake --build . --parallel
$ sudo cmake --install .
```

The goal is to have a VM on which I can compile my tools for Linux and Windows. I hope someone can help me out.

Here I am getting my ideas from:

- https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git
- [How to cross-compile Qt6 on Linux for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113095/how-to-cross-compile-qt6-on-linux-for-windows)
- https://gist.github.com/peterspackman/8cf73f7f12ba270aa8192d6911972fe8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is running in the same wrong direction as me, I found the solution then. You need the MXE cross compiler

https://mxe.cc/#tutorial

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git /opt/mxe
$ cd /opt/mxe
$ make -j$(nproc) MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.static' qt6-qtbase
```